# Testing Silverlight Apps in OS X

Tags: silverlight, macos

We're developing a Silverlight app.

Part of our whole marketing spiel is that it runs on a Mac, which for the vast majority of cases it does. However, there is the occasional OS X / Browser Combo that breaks feature X or Y. For example, most recently we're not receiving mouse events in Safari 5.1.1, in 10.6.8, etc, etc, blah blah blah.

Anyways, it's become clear that we need to spend a bit more time figuring out WHICH versions of the browser and OS actually work as advertised.

I'm not even sure how to go about this though.

Do I get a Mac Mini and use my Apple Dev account to install 4 or 5 major OS X versions and test in all those? Or is there a service that can help me with this?

Regards,
Alec

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a service for it, but it comes down to this: are you trying to make a really great app or are you just doing some LOB stuff?  If it's LOB, then maybe farming out your cross platform testing makes sense.  But if you're trying to make something really awesome, you need to do the testing yourself.  I wouldn't trust a service to know how my app should respond, if it's being as responsive as I expect, if it's consuming too much memory, etc.  For something truly great, you need to do the work (get the mac mini and try some different configs).  You might be able to make things a little easier using Fusion or Parallels to create VMs with the software configurations you desire.  (I've found on the Windows side that VMs work great for functional testing, but not as well for performance and end user responsiveness testing --YMMV.)